# updated code not showing in magento frontend

Tags: cache, css, upgrade

We are developing magento site.

when I update the code in site files, it's not displaying in frontend.

even cleared cache, but still some  colors are not updating.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "site files" you are changing as depending on this the answer could be very different.

For example if the files are css/js it could be that your merged files need to be updated. Or they could be held in your browser cache. 

If its anything php related it could be that you need to clear some php caching e.g APC or opcache.

If its theme files it is possible that maybe the theme file has been overridden by another module.

Or if you are using 1.9 and the rwd theme then you might need to compile the scss files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be are you using merge css

So rebuild it from admin under

**system -> cache management -> click on Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache**

hope this work for you.

Comment: once when i merge css and js files using system > configuration, site gave problem in frontend.

are you sure will it be the solution for my problem....

Comment: i am talking about to clear regenerate it. not to merge js may be due to conflict of js your frontend could be broke

Comment: thanks for your reply. it's problem with settings , color is initially taking settings than it will take from code, that was the problem....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emthems, go for system > configuration > Typography, there you have a option to change colors for some texts.

if you set the color in settings, if you change color in code it's not going to update.

if you remove color in settings, than code changes will apply and it will show colors.

Comment: Where are the settings? Do you mean settings from a 3rd party theme?